# Remove password from user session after login

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

When a user logs in I create a user object and store it in a session variable ( I am using express-session) . However it is also storing the hashed password in the session but I would rather not do that. Is there a way to just remove the password from the session or would I have to create a seperate session variable for everything I wanted to store in a session? eg:

```
User.findOne({email: email})
.then(user => {
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(422).render('auth/login', {
            path: '/login', 
            pageTitle: 'Login', 
            errorMessage: 'Invalid login details', 
            email: email
        });
    }
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    .then(doMatch => {
        if (doMatch) {
            req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
             req.session.user = user
             return req.session.save((err) => {
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            }); 
        }
```

So instead of req.session.user = user maybe I would have to do:

```
req.session.user.email = user.email
req.session.user.firstName = user.firstName
```

And so on. I did try this but the password still remains in the session:

```
req.session.user = { ...user }
delete req.session.user.password
```

Comment: Have you tried, `delete user.password` and then `req.session.user = user` ?

Comment: Tried that and get this error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at bcrypt.compare.then.doMatch

Comment: Instead of deleting the password after copying, did you try to copy the user object without it? `const { password, ...restOfUser } = user; req.session.user = restOfUser;` ?